# Azure dependency between jobs in worker roles

Tags: azure

Every 10 minutes several worker roles in Azure is set to process a set of jobs(100+). Some jobs are independent, but others are not. For (simple) example, a job A must be processed, send and acknowledged by a receiver before a job B can be sent.

Independent jobs can be put on queues to distribute to worker roles. I wonder if queues could work for dependent jobs in order to make a consistent solution.

Edit: I have used a too simplistic example. Jobs A and B both consist of several related messages. These messages will be distributed to n worker roles and will be sent separately, so Job A is finished when n worker roles get acks and then the messages (distributed to and processed by m worker roles) of job B can be sent.
I think in this case the only option would be to let a single worker role process both job A and B, otherwise a complex inter worker role synchronization mechanism is needed.

Comment: Job B will be sent only when one of your worker role acknowledge the completion of Job A.

Comment: Then why do you care who will process job B.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use queues to facilitate this. One possible solution would be to have the worker writing another message in same or other queue once Job A is finished. So worker will pick up the message for Job A, processes the job, writes another message that Job A is done and delete original message. Now another thread will pick up the message and start working on Job B. If the message is posted in the same queue, then the message needs to convey that it is part of a multi-job chain and what steps have been completed. If the message is posted in another queue (e.g. specific queue for Job B) then your code would know that this message is for Job B and should process it accordingly.